# Eclipse m2e Junit - ClassNotFound after mvn-Build, or resources missing after "maven update project"

Tags: java, maven, junit, m2e

I have some trouble with my Eclipse installation.

I have a Multimodule Maven Project which build just fine. All the jars are where I expect them to be and when I deploy it on my productive environment, it al works.

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Datawizard-M3-Access Parent ....................... SUCCESS [0.344s]
[INFO] m3-datawizard-access-core ......................... SUCCESS [9.474s]
[INFO] m3-datawizard-access-banking-bankAT ............... SUCCESS [0.401s]
[INFO] m3-datawizard-access-banking-denmark .............. SUCCESS [1.143s]
[INFO] m3-datawizard-access-banking-russland ............. SUCCESS [0.353s]
[INFO] m3-datawizard-access-banking-sepa ................. SUCCESS [0.378s]
[INFO] m3-datawizard-access-banking-turkey ............... SUCCESS [0.222s]
[INFO] m3-datawizard-access-gefahrgutstueckliste ......... SUCCESS [0.312s]
[INFO] m3-datawizard-access-logistik-dhl ................. SUCCESS [0.338s]
[INFO] m3-datawizard-access-logistik-exportmanager ....... SUCCESS [0.279s]
[INFO] m3-datawizard-access-logistik-fixmanagement ....... SUCCESS [0.375s]
[INFO] m3-datawizard-access-logistik-frankreich .......... SUCCESS [0.271s]
[INFO] m3-datawizard-access-logistik-landwher ............ SUCCESS [0.501s]
[INFO] m3-datawizard-access-logistik-nordic .............. SUCCESS [0.274s]
[INFO] m3-datawizard-access-logistik-turkey .............. SUCCESS [0.324s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 36.851s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Feb 14 23:37:34 CET 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 38M/358M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I then start a JUnit test after maven build, I get A ClassNotFound Exception.

```
Class not found com.lr.datawizard.cron.TurkeyLstPackagesTest
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lr.datawizard.cron.TurkeyLstPackagesTest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Even restarting Eclipse does not solve the problem.
To get rid of this Exception, I have to clean the Project by Using "Project --> Clean Project" Function of Eclipse. It is also possible to run a "Maven --> Update Project" afterwards, the test starts.

**and here is the biggest problem**
After cleaning the project (in either way) the resources from src/main/resources disappear in the target/classes folder. By that reason, my tests do not run properly anymore because they depend on some spring configuration files which are not available anymore.

In German we say "Die Katze beißt sich in den Schwanz"  (some thing like "cat bites its own tail")
I have to build the project to get everything correctly in place, but tests do not run due to (strange) ClassNotFound exception) when cleaning, the execption disappears, but also the files I need to run the tes.

Does anybody has an idea how to solve this issue?

PS:
- I reinstalled e fresh copy of eclipse (just me2 and subversive)
- I delete all .classpath, .project, .setting files/folders
- I checked out a fresh copy from svn which I am 100% sure that it worked in the , because I have some test protocols.

Don't have any ideas how to fix that. It took me 2 days now.

Answer (score 2):

After another day of playing around I found out lots of things.

**1st There seem to be something wrong with eclipse or the combination of eclipse and m2e.**
The classpath is not set correctly. When right-clicking on a project, then select "build path" --> "Configure Build path", a window opens where "Source" tab is selected.[image]

As you can see, in both source folders which are ending by "resources" there is "exclude: **"
This is not correct in my understanding. By removing it, all resources get correctly "compiled" into the classes or test-classes folder.

**Second thing is the "ClassNotFoundException" after maven build.**
This is also understandable now. In my maven run properties, I have selected "skip tests". This causes, that src/test/java is not included in the build process. That's why the class is not there and the exception is actually true.
By simply cleaning or "maven update project" after the maven build, everything is back OK again.

Imho this is an incorrect behavior of the IDE (or one of its components) but at least I know why it occurs.

I hope my answer helps someone suffering from the same problems.

Cheers, Christian

Comment: It did help..had to update Maven project after maven build to get the test folder back in build process. Thanks.